# Continuous integral function $F$

Tags: integration, analysis, continuity, proof-explanation, riemann-integration

If $f$ is continuous on rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, and if $g\in R$ on $[a,b]$, then the function $F$ defined by equation $$F(y)=\int_a^bg(x)f(x,y)dx$$ is continuous on $[c,d]$.

Proof:

If $G(x)=\int_a^xg(t)dt$, then by Theorem 1, $F(y)=\int_a^bf(x,y)dG(x)$.

Now by Theorem 2 , $F(y)=\int_a^bg(x)f(x,y)dx$ is continuous on $[c,d]$.

Theorem 1: Suppose $f\in R(\alpha)$ and $g\in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$ where $\alpha$ is increasing on $[a,b]$. We define $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)d\alpha (t)$ and $G(x)=\int_a^xg(t)d\alpha (t)$ if $x\in [a,b]$. Then $f\in R(G),g\in R(F), fg\in R(\alpha )$ on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)d\alpha (x)=\int_a^bf(x)dG(x)=\int_a^bg(x)dF(x)$.

Theorem 2: Let $f$ be a continuous function in each point $(x,y)$ of rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$. Suppose $\alpha$ is bounded variation on $[a,b]$ and let $F$ be the function defined on $[c,d]$ by $F(y)=\int_a^bf(x,y)d\alpha (x)$. Then $F$ is continuous on $[c,d]$.

How the proof apply *theorem 1*? I don't see it.

When using theorem 2, how do we know that g is bounded variation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In applying Theorem 1, let $\alpha(t) = t$.  Since $\alpha$ is increasing, the theorem guarantees that $f \in R(G)$ with

$$\int_a^b f(x,y) g(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(x,y) g(x) \, d\alpha(x) = \int_a^b f(x,y) \, dG(x),$$ where $$G(x) = \int_a^x g(t) \, d\alpha(t) = \int_a^x g(t) \, dt.$$

In applying Theorem 2, you need to satisfy the hypothesis that $G$ be of bounded variation. Note that for any Riemann integrable function $g$ the function

$$G(x) = \int_a^x g(t) \, dt$$

is of bounded variation since $g$ can be decomposed as $g = g^+ - g^-$ where $g^+ \geqslant 0$ is the positive part and $g^- \geqslant 0$ is the negative part.

Thus,

$$G(x) = \int_a^x g^+(t) \, dt - \int_a^x g^-(t) \, dt$$

is the difference of two non-decreasing functions and of bounded variation by the Jordan decomposition theorem.

Comment: I don't understand the part where you say $G$ is of bounded variation. Is it because it can be decomposed as the difference of 2 increasing functions?

Comment: Yes.  A function is of bounded variation if and only if it is the difference of two monotone increasing functions.  If $f = g - h$ is such a decomposition then for any partition using triangle inequality we have $\sum_{k =1}^n |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| \leqslant \sum_{k =1}^n |g(x_k) - g(x_{k-1})| +  \sum_{k =1}^n |h(x_k) - h(x_{k-1})| $. Now $g$ and $h$ have bounded variation since they are monotone. Thus $f$ can be shown to have bounded variation.